Expose different pods listening on different ports, with a single external IP, on EKS
I have two types of pods, with separate deployments:

pod A (running image A), listening on port 1500 (TCP)
pod B (running image B), listening on port 2000 (TCP)

For different reasons the two containers should not run in a single pod.
Both pods should be publicly exposed with a single IP, with the same ports as the pods/containers expose.
What is the canonical way to achieve that? The cluster happens to be an AWS EKS one, if this has an impact on the service type to expose those pods.

If the higher-level protocol is based on HTTP, use an Ingress (or Gateway) controller.  If it's not, how would you tell which destination a request would go to?  You might need to build your own request router in this case.

@DavidMaze it's TCP services, not HTTP, so no ingress.

how would you tell which destination a request would go to?
I don't know, hence the question.


...I missed the "with the same ports" comment, which is important (the routing question doesn't matter): you want a single load balancer which can point at both Pods on separate ports.

Do you mean something like HAProxy?
